# Getting posted values from asp server with out forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am not to sure about the way to form this question. I'm new to Web development.  We are going to post data to a server over asp.  In the example I'm playing with in Visual Studio 2012. I've created an empty project with controllers.  But how do I get the string after the path. Request file path is associated with a form and this will be view-less.

Update

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public HttpRequestBase baseRequest;

    public void Index()
    {
        if (Request.QueryString.Count > 0 && Request.QueryString[0] != null)
        {
            String surlQuery = Request.QueryString["varname"].ToString();
        }
    }

    protected override IAsyncResult BeginExecute(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        return base.BeginExecute(requestContext, callback, state);
    }
}
```

The Request.Query String is null with the project option for url set to `http://localhost:53792/test 5`

Comment: The string after what path?

Comment: Forget about the server for the moment. Show the code on the client that is trying to send to the server.

Comment: Haven't got that far yet :).. I think that's going to take form of an HttpRequest... I used something similar to get data from Google maps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Request.QueryString is an array of parameters passed in the URL.
To pass in variable you'll need to add a question mark and variable/value pairs into your url.
Example:

> example.com?variable=value&nothervar=notherval

If you're referring to passing in vars without ? and = like stack does it:

> website.com/variable/value

That would be an .htaccess solution. Something like this in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^variable/([^/]*)$ /?variable=$1 [L]
```

Don't forget to always check to make sure it's not null before trying to use it.

```
if (Request.QueryString.Count > 0 && Request.QueryString[0] != null)
```

or you can use the string name of the variable as well:

```
Request.QueryString["varname"]
```

You will have to cast/parse/convert it to whatever data type you need.

```
Request.QueryString["varname"].ToString();
int h = Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString["varname"].ToString());
```

Also, just want to point out that "post" is incorrect in this regard.
POST refers to things passed in using a form or other such that utilizes the POST protocol.
Whereas, variable in the URL are called GET.

Comment: Checking Request.QueryString is null. With project user changed to localhost:<number>/test 5.  I'm seeing it in the browser but not getting the parameter list.

Comment: GET variables are in the format var=value.
So, http://localhost:port/test 5 would need to be more like:
http://localhost:port/?variable=test%205
%20 is the ascii encoding for a space and is much better to use in a url.
Does this answer your question, or are you wanting something different?

Comment: It's not getting past the if statement

Comment: Yeah, see my amended comment above.
To pass in variables you'll need to append a question mark ? to the end of the URL plus variable name and value pairs:
site.com?variable=value

Comment: Ahhh Ok.  How are verb address? port/<verb/action><parameter>. The way I think php handles it

Comment: Cool working Thanks a bundle.  I specify the name of the variable in the browser bar and then look for the same variable in the code. Great got it. Could you tell me how to create and handles verb?

Comment: If you're referring to passing in vars without ? and = like stack does it:
website.com/variable/value
That would be an .htaccess solution.
Something like this in your .htaccess file:
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^variable/([^/]*)$ /?variable=$1 [L]

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41648/discussion-between-garaber-and-kemo-sabe)

Comment: I have edited my initial answer to reflect more data as the discussion progressed.